# C# How can i use CefSharp's DragHandler?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, cefsharp

Im trying to disable any sort of drag drop from my cefsharp browser.

I tried different codes from their documentations as well but noting seem to worked so far.

in form

```
chrmiumBrwsr.DragHandler = new CustomDragHandler();
```

-

```
    public class CustomDragHandler : IDragHandler
{
    bool IDragHandler.OnDragEnter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IDragData dragData, DragOperationsMask mask)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void IDragHandler.OnDraggableRegionsChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IList<DraggableRegion> regions)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IDragHandler_OnDragEnter.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `dragData.Dispose();` before `return false;` and change that into `return true;`

Final code:

```
public class CustomDragHandler : IDragHandler
{
    bool IDragHandler.OnDragEnter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IDragData dragData, DragOperationsMask mask)
    {
        dragData.Dispose();
        return true;
    }

    void IDragHandler.OnDraggableRegionsChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IList<DraggableRegion> regions)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```